# Unexpected Behavior with Remix/ Node.js/ React,

Tags: reactjs, node.js, remix

I’m currently working on a project using Remix, Node.js, and React, and I’ve run into an issue that I can’t seem to resolve.

Here’s the situation: I have a function Test1
that returns a JSX element.

```js
<h1>hello</h1>
```

I’m exporting this function using

```js
module.exports = Test1
```

and importing it in another file using

```js
const Test1 = require('.1data/test1.server')
```

When I run my app, the text from the `Test1`
function is displayed correctly for a split second, however, it then disappears, and I get the following error:

```js
createFiberFromTypeAndProps@https://rear-signup-tickets-
moscow.trycloudflare.com/build/_shared/chunk-, etc...
```

(wouldnt let me post
the full error)

I’m not sure what’s causing this. If anyone has any insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If the error is too big, please provide the relevant portions which may not be the first part of the error.  The error you posted does not provide much information on your problem.